# document.getElementByID().submit() not working

Tags: javascript, submit

I am working on an applescript together with javascript.
I am totally new to javascript and I am struggling with a simple "submit" action of an input.

[image]

I tried the following standard line, but it's not working:
do JavaScript "`document.getElementByID('form-submit').click()`" in document 1

Could anyone help me out here? I read already somewhere that there could be an issue with the fact that the input is `type=submit`. But I don' know how to handle this.

Thanks a lot!
Carlo

Comment: `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementByID` - case sensitive

Comment: And put a value to the submit input

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the quick response! And yes, you're right, it was just the case sensitive mistake. How stupid is that! I wasted 2 hours with this one and it's so easy. Shame on me...

Comment: It happens, I'm sure most people working with JS have been burned on that at least once or twice in the past.

Comment: @CarloP console is your friend - It should warn you about that, take look ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your problem, @CarloP, is you used `document.getElementByID` to get the element in the DOM. Instead, use `document.getElementById`. Notice I changed `ID` to `Id`.